# Brewing with Molasses

Tags: fermentation

I am using Molasses for brewing and I have problems getting the fermentation to start. There are no brewing supplies where I live and I would like to know if anyone can tell me of a household product I could use to enhance the fermentation process.

DJ. Simms

Comment: We need more details to help. Please add your general recipe and process you've done so far.

Comment: How much molasses? And how much sugars overall?

Answer (score 1):

As 'Evil Zymurgist' says more details would help here, but... if you are brewing with pure Molasses then you will be lacking many nutrients required for a healthy/rapid fermentation. Acids such as citric, also you are likely lacking enough nitrogen/amino acids for a vigorous fermentation.

For acid you could add lemon or orange juice, regarding adding nitrogen to the mix you could boil up some raisins or apples and add the pulp to the mix. It will probably ferment to completion without these, but will be far happier with.

Couple of pounds of Molasses, 1 mashed up apple or hand full of raisins, juice of an orange, made up to a gallon should ferment fine. Not sure how it will taste, but fermentation wise it should be OK.

This reminds me of making a mead, but with Molasses rather than honey.

Comment: I'd skip the up-front acid additions. You can also make "yeast hulls" by boiling bread yeast to use as a nutrient.